# Finding amount of water in a hemisphere using integration

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

> A bowl shaped like a hemisphere with radius 60 cm is partially filled with water. The depth of the water is 10cm in the center of the bowl. How many liters of water are in the bowl?

My somewhat silly attempt to solve this was the following: 1/6th of the bowl is filled with water (I think), and the volume of a hemisphere is $(2/3)\pi r^3$, the amount of liters of water in the bowl must be 1/6th of that: $(1/9 )\pi r^3$ which not surprisingly gave the wrong answer. I know I'm supposed to solve this using integration; I just don't know where to begin.

Comment: Just because the depth of the water at the center is 1/6 of the radius of the bowl, doesn't mean the volume of water is 1/6 of the volume of the bowl.  Have you drawn a picture?  Can you set this up as a solid-of-revolution problem?

Comment: Please remember to check mark an answer to resolve the problem, or ask for more clarification to make sure we have the answer you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bowl can be modeled in 2-D by the equation $x^2+y^2=60^2$. We will make that in terms of $y$ to be $y=\sqrt{3600-x^2}$. We know the bounds are $50, 60$ because your shape is $10$ cm deep. In order to calculate the volume sweeped out by the curve between $50, 60$, we use the integral
$$\pi\int_{50}^{60}\sqrt{3600-x^2}^2 dx$$
where the $\pi \sqrt{3600-x^2}^2 dx$ is the volume of a tiny cylindrical slice of your shape, and the integral is to add up those infinitelay many infinitely thin cylindrical slices into the shape the water forms in the bowl.

I think you can calculate the integral on your own.

Comment: Good answer.  Although I might interchange the roles of $x$ and $y$, since $x$ is usually drawn horizontally and water falls vertically.

Comment: @D.R. How do you know the circle x^2 +y^2 = 60^2 becomes a hemisphere when you revolve it around the x-axis? I also don't really get what is meant by "the depth of the water is 10cm in the center of the bowl". I mean the bowl is filled up from the bottom right, not the middle? I have trouble understanding why the integration limits must be exactly 50,60.

Comment: @Pame My hemisphere is rotated 90 degrees counterclockwise. In my example, "down" resides at positive infinity on the x axis, instead of the usual negative infinity on the y axis, and "up" is at negative infinity on the x axis. The bounds are 50,60 because 60 is the "bottom" of my hemisphere, and moving "up" 10 cm gets us to 50.

Comment: @D.R I get it now. It makes sense if you think about how the shape looks like when you revolve it around the x-axis. Thanks for the help. By the way, the depth of each disk is dx right? But from what i see we never actually multiply by dx, we just write it in the formula. Yet if we don't multiply the disk areas with their depth we never get any volume. So how come dx isn't something we actually multiply with?